# ORA-01109 Database not open error while running a script

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am running a script with SQLPlus in an Oracle DB which creates extra tablespaces. Here is the code of the script:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE FAR_YELLOW_FISH
DATAFILE
    '$ORADATA/node03/faryellowfish01.dbf' SIZE 200M,
    '$ORADATA/node03/faryellowfish02.dbf' SIZE 200M;
CREATE TABLESPACE WET_BROWN_SOUP
DATAFILE
    '$ORADATA/node01/wetbrownsoup01.dbf' SIZE 100M,
    '$ORADATA/node03/wetbrownsoup02.dbf' SIZE 100M;
CREATE TABLESPACE EASY_ORANGE_DISK
DATAFILE
    '$ORADATA/node03/easyorangedisk01.dbf' SIZE 100M,
    '$ORADATA/node03/easyorangedisk02.dbf' SIZE 100M,
    '$ORADATA/node02/easyorangedisk03.dbf' SIZE 100M,
    '$ORADATA/node02/easyorangedisk04.dbf' SIZE 100M;
CREATE TABLESPACE WET_YELLOW_OVEN
DATAFILE
    '$ORADATA/node01/wetyellowoven01.dbf' SIZE 100M;
```

Before this I run the following:

```
sqlplus /nolog
connect / as sysdba
create SPFILE from PFILE;
startup nomount
```

and a script which creates main tablespaces - it works properly.
When running the script, that I mentioned first, I get the following error: `ORA-01109: database not open`. It appears for each `CREATE TABLESPACE` expression.
As a solution I tried to run `ALTER DATABASE OPEN;` but the answer was `ORA-01507: database not mounted`.
I guess, there is something wrong with the script, but not sure about that.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your startup script isn't starting the database.

To start the database, do this:

```
sqlplus /nolog
connect / as sysdba
startup
```

Also, do not use environment variables (i.e. $ORADATA) in your SQL script. sqlplus won't know what they mean. Include the full path.